# JqGrid: Setting the position for the "No Rows Selected" dialog

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

So I found some good fixes for centering the confirm delete, edit, view etc dialog boxes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10335710/1532659). However, when **no rows** are selected on the grid, a different dialog will appear that shows a simple "Warning: Please, select row." Besides this dialog having horrible grammar, I can't seem to find anyway of handling this dialog's events so that I can reposition as desired.

I added handlers for every event in the navGrid I could find and used BugZilla to see if it would stop on any of these events to no avail. ***When rows are selected***, it will fire the delete event fine. Ideas? Below is my code:

```
$('#sessionGrid').jqGrid({...}).navGrid('#sessionPager', { 
            add: false,
            edit: false,
            del: true,
            search: false,
            closeOnEscape: true
        }, {
            afterShowForm: function (form) {
                form.closest('div.ui-jqdialog').center();
            }
        }, {
            afterShowForm: function (form) {
                form.closest('div.ui-jqdialog').center();
            }
        }, {
            caption: "Delete",
            msg: "Delete the selected sessions?",
            bSubmit: "Delete",
            bCancel: "Cancel",
            afterShowForm: function (form) {
                form.closest('div.ui-jqdialog').center();
            }
        }, {
            afterShowForm: function (form) {
                form.closest('div.ui-jqdialog').center();
            }
        }, {
            afterShowForm: function (form) {
                form.closest('div.ui-jqdialog').center();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code in [grid.formedit.js](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/master/js/) is used to display this dialog:

```
if (o.del) {
    tbd = $("<td class='ui-pg-button ui-corner-all'></td>");
    pDel = pDel || {};
    $(tbd).append("<div class='ui-pg-div'><span class='ui-icon "+o.delicon+"'></span>"+o.deltext+"</div>");
    $("tr",navtbl).append(tbd);
    $(tbd,navtbl)
    .attr({"title":o.deltitle || "",id: pDel.id || "del_"+elemids})
    .click(function(){
        if (!$(this).hasClass('ui-state-disabled')) {
            var dr;
            if($t.p.multiselect) {
                dr = $t.p.selarrrow;
                if(dr.length===0) {dr = null;}
            } else {
                dr = $t.p.selrow;
            }
            if(dr){
                if($.isFunction( o.delfunc )){
                    o.delfunc.call($t, dr);
                }else{
                    $($t).jqGrid("delGridRow",dr,pDel);
                }
            } else  {
// !!! The actual dialog is displayed here  -
                $.jgrid.viewModal("#"+alertIDs.themodal,{gbox:"#gbox_"+$.jgrid.jqID($t.p.id),jqm:true});$("#jqg_alrt").focus();
            }
        }
        return false;
    }).hover(
        function () {
            if (!$(this).hasClass('ui-state-disabled')) {
                $(this).addClass("ui-state-hover");
            }
        },
        function () {$(this).removeClass("ui-state-hover");}
    );
    tbd = null;
}
```

Unfortunately jqGrid does not expose an event for this. But you might have luck binding your own function to the delete button's `click` event. In the same file you can see how the DOM ID is assigned to the delete button:

```
.attr({"title":o.deltitle || "",id: pDel.id || "del_"+elemids})
```

In essence, you can either pass the `id` parameter as part of the delete parameters, or if you do not it will default to `elemids` which is assigned the DOM ID of your grid (EG: your selector would be `'#del_mygrid'`).

Anyway, then you can use something like `jQuery('div.ui-jqdialog').center();` in your `click` event handler to reposition the dialog as needed.

Does that help?

---

As an aside, the actual dialog text is in `grid.locale-en.js` -

> alerttext: "Please, select row",

I agree this is horrible :)
The good news is that this is a separate js file, so you can revise it as necessary.

Comment: Yeah that helps a lot. Thanks heaps!