# how to move to the dialog box immediate to the above of ROW for which delete action is performed

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a jquery grid with over 100 rows and when user interact with the rows of grid (example delete a row), a popup appears near the top of the grid.

If user had previously scrolled the page near to last record, the model popup will not immediately visible and the user will not be able to continue unless he scrolls back to the top of the grid.

It is possible to move to the dialog box immediate to the above of ROW for which delete action is performed, so that it immediate visible to user?

```
onCellSelect : function(rowid)
  {
     $(this).jqGrid('ViewGridRow', rowid, {viewPageButton:false, width:800, height: auto})
  }
```

I tried below code to set some top position, but not work,

```
onCellSelect : function(rowid)
  {
     $(this).jqGrid('ViewGridRow', rowid, {top: "50%", viewPageButton:false, width:800, height: auto})
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree that default position of Delete dialog is not good. I posted many ways how one can change the behavior. For example [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5720456/315935) provide the demo which do almost what you need. [Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8491939/315935) demonstrate how to create context menu from the buttons of navigator bar. Combination of both solutions allows to create the best comfort for the user. The user can use context menu to see all actions from the navigation menu without need to scroll the grid. Choosing of Add/Edit or Delete items of menu created dialog on the same position.