# jqgrid edit dialog align to center

Tags: jqgrid, dialog, edit, center

I am using jqgrid in my application.
I need the edit dialog should be center aligned.
I tried to search a way but failed. If any one have the solution please let me know.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/CenterEditForm.htm) from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967488/how-to-center-jqgrid-popup-modal-window/3968981#3968981).

One more way to solve the same problem you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5719490/jqgrid-reposition-delete-confirmation-box/5720456#5720456). In the case the position of the dialog will be based on the current selected row.