# JqGrid, how to center delete box?

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

in My Jqgrid i have a column with delete links, everything works perfect, except that delete confirmation box pops up at top left corner all the time. i want to have the confirmation box in center of the jqgrid, not in top left corner.

```
{ name: 'act', index: 'act', width: 150, align: 'center', sortable: false}],

          gridComplete: function () {

              var rows = jQuery("#list").jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow');
              var ids = jQuery("#list").jqGrid('getDataIDs');
              var gr = jQuery('#list'); gr.setGridHeight("auto", true);
              for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
                  var cl = ids[i];
                  be = "<a href='#' style='height:25px;width:120px;' type='button' value='Slet' onclick=\"jQuery('#list').jqGrid('delGridRow','" + cl + "',{reloadAfterSubmit:false, url:'@Url.Action("deleteRow")'}); return false;\">Slet </>";
                  jQuery("#list").jqGrid('setRowData', ids[i], { act: be });   
              }
          },
```

**UPDATE**

```
be = "<a href='#' style='height:25px;width:120px;' type='button' value='Slet' onclick=\"jQuery('#list').jqGrid('delGridRow','" + cl + "', myDelParameters); return false;\">Slet </>";
```

*code for my Global variable:*

```
myDelParameters = {reloadAfterSubmit:false, url:'@Url.Action("deleteRow")',  beforeShowForm: function(form) {
              // "editmodlist"
      var dlgDiv = jQuery("#list").jqGrid("#delmodlist" + grid[0].id);
              var parentDiv = dlgDiv.parent(); // div#gbox_list
              var dlgWidth = dlgDiv.width();
              var parentWidth = parentDiv.width();
              var dlgHeight = dlgDiv.height();
              var parentHeight = parentDiv.height();
              // TODO: change parentWidth and parentHeight in case of the grid
              //       is larger as the browser window
              dlgDiv[0].style.top = Math.round((parentHeight-dlgHeight)/2) + "px";
              dlgDiv[0].style.left = Math.round((parentWidth-dlgWidth)/2) + "px";
          }};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You set already some parameters of the [delGridRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#delgridrow) method (see `{reloadAfterSubmit:false, url:...` in your code).

My suggestion that you use `afterShowForm` in the list of [delGridRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#delgridrow) parameters. The implementation of the `afterShowForm` could be like in [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967488/how-to-center-jqgrid-popup-modal-window/3968981#3968981), but with the usage of `"#delmodlist"` (`"#delmod" + grid[0].id`, where `var grid = $("#list")`)  instead of `$("#editmod" + grid[0].id)`.

Another more short form of the implementation could be with respect of [jQuery UI Position](http://jqueryui.com/demos/position/):

```
afterShowForm = function ($form) {
    $form.closest('div.ui-jqdialog').position({
        my: "center",
        of: $("#list").closest('div.ui-jqgrid')
    });
}
```

In [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithCenterForms.htm) I use such function for all Add/Edit and Delete forms.

**UPDATED**: It seems to me that you have implementation problems. I made [one more demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithDelButton.htm) which you can easy modify to what you want. I don't set any `editurl`, so if you press "Delete" button the error will be displayed. Moreover the HTML fragment which you try to place in the 'act' column is a combination of `<a>` and `<button>` settings. Because I don't know what you wanted I placed just `<a>` in the 'act' column. I hope now you can easy modify my demo to make your program working.

Here is the schema of the code from [my demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithDelButton.htm) which you can use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var myDelParameters = {
        reloadAfterSubmit: false,
        //url:'@Url.Action("deleteRow")',
        afterShowForm: function ($form) {
            'use strict';
            $form.closest('div.ui-jqdialog').position({
                my: "center",
                of: $("#list").closest('div.ui-jqgrid')
            });
        }
    };
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var grid = $("#list"),
            centerForm = function ($form) {
                $form.closest('div.ui-jqdialog').position({
                    my: "center",
                    of: grid.closest('div.ui-jqgrid')
                });
            },
            getColumnIndexByName = function (mygrid, columnName) {
                var cm = mygrid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'colModel'), i = 0, l = cm.length;
                for (; i < l; i += 1) {
                    if (cm[i].name === columnName) {
                        return i; // return the index
                    }
                }
                return -1;
            };

        grid.jqGrid({
            colModel: [
                ...
                {name: 'action', index: 'action', width: 70, align: 'center', sortable: false},
                ...
            ],
            ...
            loadComplete: function () {
                var iCol = getColumnIndexByName($(this), 'action'), iRow, row,
                    rows = this.rows,
                    cRows = rows.length;

                for (iRow = 0; iRow < cRows; iRow += 1) {
                    row = rows[iRow];
                    if ($.inArray('jqgrow', row.className.split(' ')) > 0) {
                        $(row.cells[iCol]).html("<a href='#' style='height:25px;width:120px;' onclick=\"jQuery('#list').jqGrid('delGridRow','" +
                            row.id + "',myDelParameters); return false;\">Del</>");
                    }
                }
            });
    });
//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: I just cant get it to fit.... how should it look inside of  jQuery("#list").jqGrid('navGrid', "#page", { edit: false, add: false, del: false }, { beforeShowForm: function(form) {   }});});

Comment: @Timsen: Yes, you can use inline function definition, but somewhere near `reloadAfterSubmit:false`: for example  `{reloadAfterSubmit:false, , url:'@Url.Action("deleteRow"), beforeShowForm: function($form) {... }`. One more possibility is if you define the *global* function (defined on the top level) and use the function by name like `beforeShowForm: myFormCenter`. You can also define the *global* object `var myDelParameters = {reloadAfterSubmit:false, url:'@Url.Action("deleteRow")', beforeShowForm: function($form) {... }};`  and use `... cl + "', myDelParameters);  return false;`

Comment: doesnt work, when im creating global variable and put it inside of my link, action is not called at all. i updated code in main,you can see my global variable and new link code

Comment: You have cut&paste error. The statement `var dlgDiv = jQuery("#list").jqGrid("#delmodlist" + grid[0].id)` is wrong. It should be either `var dlgDiv = $("#delmodlist");` or `var grid = $("#list"), dlgDiv = $("#delmod" + grid[0].id);`. I modified the text of my answer to describe all more clear.

Comment: its moved now, but its moved to the top center :D

Comment: @Timsen: I updated my answer one more time to make it easy for you to implement what you need in your code.

Comment: Works now, i used myDelParameters with aftershowform instead and it worked. thank you oleg. Thumbs up

Answer (score 0):

for centering the jqdialog and display near the row selected
.ui-jqdialog{position:fixed; left:415px;}
This is working perfect for my requirement.
Thank You