# How do I control the layout of the pop-up form (alignment)

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net, jqgrid-formatter

I Use JqGrid jquery plugin, i Want to use insert popup Capability, but I'll look into it when the controls are arranged,How can we control the order(alignment)
[image]

[image]

I would like to be in.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no experience in RTL languages, but if I use `direction: 'rtl'` [option](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options) of jqGrid I have much better results as in your screen shorts:

[image]

see [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/UnicodeRTL.htm). I hope the demo will help you.

**UPDATED**: It seems to me there are a bug in the `ui.jqgrid.css` in the line which defines style for `.ui-jqdialog-content .CaptionTD`. One should remove `text-align: left;` from the style settings to inherit the `text-align` style from the parent. One can fix the problem by including the following additional CSS after the `ui.jqgrid.css` in case of usage RTL language:

```
.ui-jqdialog-content .CaptionTD {text-align: right;}
```

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/UnicodeRTL1.htm) which uses modified CSS display the edit form as the following:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @ Oleg, but RTL isn't my problem, my problem is label and Control(example textbox or DropDownlist) no align.,The labels are not in control and on top of them is thanks

Comment: @mohsen: Sorry, but I wrote you already that I have *no experience* with RTL languages. So I really don't understand what you mean under "... label and Control(example textbox or DropDownlist) no align. The labels are not in control and on top of them". What you mean?  Should be the text in the labels right aligned? Should text in the controls be left alignment? Could you post pictures or URLs which show clear which behavior is correct? Do you know some other RTL languages? Which alignment behavior are used in another RTL languages?

Comment: in Pic next post i want align textbox and caption. and How can remove Gap(free space) between textbox and titie textbox(example id)

Comment: @ Oleg, i want change popup window design  to pic next post,plese help me. thanks

Comment: @mohsen: I wrote in my comment to your picture below that I recommend you to look [the video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/MIX/MIX09/C17F) about ergonomic web forms. The **form design** is not the problem, but you should either use existing forms of write relatively long code which generate *your own* styled forms. You should decide yourself what is your choose and whether your customers are ready pay for *new development* instead of usage some exiting *free* one.

Comment: @mohsen: You still not commented the UPDATED part of my answer. Is the right alignment of the labels is common practice for the RTL languages? If it is so I will post the corresponding bug fix to trirand forum and the fix will be probably included in the next version of jqGrid.

Comment: @mohsen: I don't receive any confirmation from you about the correct alignment of the labels in the form. So I just posted [the bug report](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/wrong-alignment-of-labels-in-forms-with-rtl-languages/#p25804) with the description of the problem how I understand it.

Comment: @mohsen: You are welcome! Is the suggestion from [the bug report](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/wrong-alignment-of-labels-in-forms-with-rtl-languages/#p25804) correct described the standard alignment of the labels?

Comment: @mohsen: Thanks for you too for the confirmation. Do you found now where you had CSS problem in your project?

Comment: @ Oleg,yes but i can't impelment tow column in popup windows

Comment: @mohsen: I don't recommend you to spend your time for it. Just set `max-height` value for example (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8420646/315935)) or set `height` parameter so that scrolling is correct. In the case the user will be able quickly find all the information which the user want to change.  If you would write the multi-column form you will have a few benefit from a lot of efforts. It's not economical.