# rowpos and colpos in beforShowForm

Tags: jqgrid

Is there an option to include `rowpos` and `colpos` in `beforShowForm`. I understand that it should be used under `formoption` setting of `colModel`. but my grid has customised edit (say status) and normal edit. I want different alignment for these two. below are my code for reference

```js
bulkgrid.jqGrid('navGrid','#bulkktrackpager',{   
    edit: true,   
    add: true,   
    del: true,    
    search: true,    
    view: true,    
    //cloneToTop: true,
}).navButtonAdd('#bulkktrackpager',{   
    caption:"Status",      
    buttonicon:"ui-icon-lightbulb",      
    position:"last",    
});
```

any idea???? many thanks..

```
    }).navButtonAdd('#bulkktrackpager',{
     caption:"Status", 
     buttonicon:"ui-icon-lightbulb", 
     position:"last",
     onClickButton: function(){ 
             var $self = $(this);
             $self.jqGrid("editGridRow", $self.jqGrid("getGridParam", "selrow"),
                {
                    beforeInitData: function(formid) {
                        bulkgrid.setColProp('status', {
                            formoptions : {
                                rowpos : 1,
                                colpos: 1,
                            },
                        });
                        bulkgrid.setColProp('ctno', {
                            formoptions : {
                                rowpos : 1,
                                colpos: 2,
                            },

                        });
                        //similaryly other elements
                    },  
                     beforeShowForm: function(form) { 
                         $("#tr_agent").hide();
                    },
                    recreateForm: true,
                    editData: {//Function to Add parameters to the status 
                        oper: 'status',
                    },
                    closeAfterEdit: true,
                    reloadAfterSubmit: true,
                });
    }
});
```

Images [image]
Image2 [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `rowpos` and `colpos` properties of [formoptions](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#formoptions). You can set the values *dynamically* inside of `beforeInitData` callback. You should use `recreateForm: true` option additionally to be sure that jqGrid uses the current values.

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/MulticolumnEdit.htm) created for [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10852741/315935) demonstrate "static" usage of `rowpos` and `colpos` properties of [formoptions](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#formoptions). If you need to change alignment of all labels of the you can set `text-align` style (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8995258/315935)). Alternatively you can set CSS style `text-align` for specific labels only. You need to set the style inside of `beforeShowForm` callback for example.

Comment: wow! clean and clear solution. dynamic rowpos and colpos works like a charm. will try text-align later. thanks Oleg.

Comment: @oleg.. dont understand why after mentioning recreateForm: true, getting same form model for edit and status. i updated the codes in my question..

Comment: @Wahab: Do you have some problem? What works incorrect now? The code seems correct. I personally prefer to redefine default values of form editing with `jQuery.extend(jQuery.jgrid.edit, {...});`  instead of inserting the option like `recreateForm: true, closeAfterEdit: true, reloadAfterSubmit: true`. I would use also `$this` or `$(this)` instead of `bulkgrid` in the code of `beforeInitData` and remove trailing `","` after `reloadAfterSubmit: true` to be more strict to JavaScript language.

Comment: the problem i am facing is for normal edit and status (added in navButtonAdd) has same form elements and form structure. i want different elements and different structure. here status overrides edit elements

Comment: updated images for your reference. here both edit and status shows same form

Comment: @Wahab: What exactly should be different? Do you use different `rowpos` and `colpos` in both cases? Do you used `recreateForm: true` in both cases? Do you tried to *overwrite* default value `recreateForm: false` to `true` with respect of `jQuery.extend(jQuery.jgrid.edit, {...});` like I suggested in my previous comment? If you don't want to do this you have to set `recreateForm: true` option in `navGrid` (see `prmEdit` and `prmAdd` parameters in [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:navigator#definition) of `navGrid`).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38140/discussion-between-wahab-and-oleg)

Comment: What exactly should be different? ---> status form should be a subset of edit with different rowpos and colpos (some fields are hidden).
Do you use different rowpos and colpos in both cases? --> yes
Do you used recreateForm: true in both cases? ---> yes
Do you tried to overwrite default value recreateForm: false to true with respect of jQuery.extend(jQuery.jgrid.edit, {...}); like I suggested in my previous comment? ---> yes
updates 1. normal edit works fine.   2. status edit shows different alignment. (some fields are hidden and aligned @ different position)